# DotNetOpenId problem when publishing it

Tags: asp.net, iis, openid, dotnetopenauth

I have the following problem:
I developed and OpenID authentication system on C#, it worked perfectly on my LocalHost, but when I published it, I keep getting this error messages, what should I do?
Thank you!

```
Error:System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint found.
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(Boolean condition, String message, Object[] args)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingPartyControlBase.LogOn()
   at WikiLoader.Login.OpenId_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Source: System.Web

Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Stack trace:    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.login_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: It has a problem with discovery. Are you sure it can connect to the identity url? (Could cause problems e.g. if you use `http://localhost/openid` as identifier, while the RP is somewhere else than localhost) It's impossible to tell you much more with only the data you've provided.

Comment: Mmm, well, it only uses Google, Yahoo, Chi.mp and MyOpenID as identifiers. I haven't used localhost as identifier. My code is the following one: 

//Ask for log in, or stop using it.
                openIDLogin.LoggedIn += new EventHandler<DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdEventArgs>(openIDLogin_LoggedIn);

Answer (score 0):

[Turn on logging](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/) and see what they tell you.

This usually is because your production server has a safeguard (firewall, proxy, etc.) that prevents outgoing HTTP requests, which of course OpenID requires.